# How can I compare only the schema for dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As the title says, I only want to compare if the data types and the column names for two dataframes are same or not. I'm not concerned about the values being equal.

From what I've already tried, .equals() compares value as well, and if I try to compare empty dataframes they are always resulting in not being equal (also, I lose out on the dtypes attribute).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Compare `Series` created by [`DataFrame.dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
df1.dtypes.equals(df2.dtypes)
```

**Sample**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4.0,5,4,5,5,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

df4 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'C':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})
```

---

```
print (df1.dtypes.equals(df2.dtypes))
True

print (df1.dtypes.equals(df3.dtypes))
False

print (df1.dtypes.equals(df4.dtypes))
False
```

Comment: If you want to see the differences: `set(df1.dtypes.index) ^ set(df2.dtypes.index)` for the columns, and `set(df1.dtypes) ^ set(df2.dtypes)` for the types